# SSIS - Flat file conection with same column/row delimiter

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I have a *.txt file. And the data format is like below :

```
Guest|Orient| |HMI1|0|-480|
Guest2|Orient2| |HMI1|0|-480|
```

It will not format correctly when I preview the data.
Already try all row delimiter-CRLF,CR,LF,;,:,tab,|.

Need advice.
Thanks

Comment: Under `Columns` in Column Delimiter put `Vertical Bar {|}`. Row delimiter should stay as it is (newline sign). If you put | as Row delimiter, you get new row for each | in the file.

Comment: yes.. i already put | for column. BUT dont know what to put for ROW delimiter. Cause it is not working fine when I preview it.